# dynamic dropdown is populated ONLY if I click on it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I have a textbox (auto-complete) where users can enter an actor/actress name which works fine.
As soon as user insert a name in the textbox, a dynamic dropdown should be populated showing list of movies by that actor.

### Problem:

when user insert a name in the textbox, an empty dropdown is populated, but if user click on the dropdown or somewhere in the page, then list of movies are shown in the dropdown! Another issue is that if user press Enter inside the textbox (after he inserted the name), the textbox will be cleared!!
Could someone kindly let me know what is the problem with my code?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="res/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree-1.0.7.js"type="text/javascript"type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <p>
                <input type="textbox" name= "tag" id="tags" placeholder="Enter an actor/actress name here" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <select id="movieName" name="movieName[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px" style="display:none;">
                </select>
            </p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#tags").autocomplete({
                    source: "actorsauto.php",
                    minLength: 2,
                    focus: function( event, ui ){
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui){
                        $("#tags").on('autocompletechange change', function () {
                            var selectedVal = $(this).val();
                            $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){
                                console.log(response);
                                $("#movieName").html(response).show();
                            });
                        }).change();
                     }
                });
            });
        </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is actions.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$html = "";
if(isset($_POST['q']) && !empty($_POST['q'])){
    try{ 
        include('imdbConnection.php');
        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM cast_movie WHERE castName = :q");
        $sql->execute(array(':q' => $_POST['q']));
        while($rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $option = '<option value="' . $rows['movieName'] . '">' . $rows['movieName'] . '</option>';
            $html .= $option;
        }   
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo $html; 
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this part.

```
$("#tags").on('autocompletechange change', function () {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){
        console.log(response);                                            
        $("#movieName").html(response).show();
    });
}).change();
```

Action will be made on "change". .  try to change it as on "keyup"
change will only be trigger if the element loses its focus.

EDIT: you should change this part ..

```
 $("#tags").on('autocompletechange keyup', function () {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){
        console.log(response);                                            
        $("#movieName").html(response).show();
    });
}).keyup();
```

Comment: sorry, could you please explain more? (I mean how should I change to keyup change?)

Comment: i have edited my answer, im not sure if it will work. try it and let me know.

Comment: should I change the last line too? --> `}).change()`

Comment: @mOna yes. change that part too.

Comment: it didn't change anything :(

Comment: when I press F12 in target.html page, I see that when I enter a name in the textbox, first response is `""`,and then when I click on the dropdown or somewhere in the page, I see all option values (movies) in the console .. I am not sure but I think the problem is that it first populate a dropdown and then put the response values inside dropdown...